# Install libvirt with xenserver api support

Tags: xen, libvirt

I want to have a try to install libvirt on my ubuntu PC to manage a remote xenserver,
but there's some problem blocks me..
I download the libvirt source package .
when in this step :

```
./configure --with-esx --with-xenapi --prefix=/opt/libvirt
```

> checking for xen_vm_start in -lxenserver... no
>       configure: error: You must install the XenServer Library to
>   compile XenAPI driver with -lxenserver

I get this error, I found that XenAPI driver is "libxenserver", I get it from this site:
http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Download+SDKs

but how should I do with the libxenserver?
is there someone who has successfully installed the libvirt with xenserver support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it working. You just need to put libxenserver.so.1.3 in /usr/lib/

Then make symbolic links to libxenserver.so.1 and libxenserver.so

After that if you're still having trouble do a ldconfig.

FYI I'm doing this is Fedora 16.